# i am fairly new to c++ and i have tried making a log class but have gotten multiple errors and dont know how to fix. I tried watching tutorials but

Tags: c++

error messages like:undefined identifier for m_LogLevel variable expected identifiers from line 40-46.

I have tried using the log functions without the fullstops. I simply dont have any more ideas in my reviewing i did not see any issues within the log.

```
#include <iostream>

class Log {

   private:
        const int LogLevelWarning = 1;
        const int LogLevelError = 0;
        const int LogLevelInfo = 2;

    private:
        int Loglevel = LogLevelInfo;
    public:
        void SetLevel(int level) {
            int m_Loglevel;
        }
        void Info(const char* message) {
    
            if (m_LogLevel >= LogLevelInfo) {
                std::cout << "[Info]" << message << "\n";
            }
        }
        void Warn(const char* message) {
            if (m_LogLevel >= LogLevelWarning) {
                std::cout << "[WARNING]" << message << "\n";
            }
        }
    
        void Error(const char* message) {
            if (m_LogLevel >= Lo

gLevelError) {
            std::cout << "[Errror]" << message << "\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    
        
        Log log;
        Log.SetLevel(Log.LogLevelWarning);
        Log.Warn("Hello!");
        Log.Info("Hey!")
        Log.Error("Hi!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void SetLevel(int level) {
        int m_Loglevel;
}
```

The scope of m_Loglevel is just restricted to the SetLevel function. It won't be visible anywhere else. You can read more about scopes here [C++ Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160) 
Also you're just declaring it with no initialization. It just contains garbage value.
You should rather set the 'LogLevel' to be 'level' which is passed as parameter. Like so:

```
 void SetLevel(int level) {
        LogLevel = level;
 }
```

And then ofcourse, replace 'm_LogLevel' with just 'LogLevel' in other functions aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite code:
Instead of

```
private:
        int Loglevel = LogLevelInfo;
    public:
        void SetLevel(int level) {
            int m_Loglevel;
        }
```

write as follow:

```
private:
        int m_Loglevel = LogLevelInfo;
    public:
        void SetLevel(int level) {
            m_Loglevel = level;
        }
```